# Using a string variable in Xpath syntax

Tags: excel, vba, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a list of image names on Excel that I need to find on a website.

Can I use a string variable within the Xpath syntax to find all these images one by one through a for-next loop?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
dim bot as new chromedriver, variable1 as string
bot.get "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"

For a = 1 to 10
    varaiable1 = cells(a,1).value
    bot.findelementbyxpath("//img[contains(@alt,variable1)]").click
next a
```

It does work when I use specific string value, say 'clean':

```
bot.findelementbyxpath("//img[contains(@alt,'clean')],")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix, variable1 is a... variable, so you must concatenate the values using &

```
bot.findelementbyxpath("//img[contains(@alt," & variable1 & ")]").click
```

Comment: Hey @francesco giossi thanks for looking into this. I tried this exactly as you mentioned but it doesn't work and gets back with the same error.

Comment: actually it worked with a slight change in syntax. Thanks @Francesco